# Finite dimensional distribution of a stochastic process Lipschitz on every relatively compact set

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $X_t$ be a Markovian Itô diffusion process, defined by an SDE
\begin{equation}
dX_t = \mu(X_t)dt + \sigma(X_t)dW_t\,.
\end{equation}

Let $f(x,t|x_0,0)$ denote its transition density function. Under suitable conditions, as is my case, we know that $f$ is Lipschitz on every relatively compact set $S$ with associated constant $C_S$.

Due to the Markovian property, we have that
\begin{equation}
f(x_1,t_1;x_2,t_2;...;x_n,t_n|x_0,t_0) = f(x_n,t_n|x_{n-1},t_{n-1}) \ldots f(x_2,t_2|x_{1},t_{1})
f(x_1,t_1|x_0,t_0)\,.
\end{equation}

Does this imply that the finite dimensional distribution is Lipschitz on $S^n$ as well (in terms of $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$)? And, if so, can such a constant be explicitly determined as well in terms of some $C_S$'s?

Comment: In what sense is the transition density $f$ locally Lipschitz? Writing $f(x,t; y, s)$ is the function locally Lipschitz in $(x, t, y, s) \in \mathbb{R}^d\times \mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}_+$ or only in $(x,t)$ for fixed $(y,s)$? If the first is true then I believe your claim is true. If I am not wrong the product of locally Lipschitz functions is locally Lipschitz. Also shouldn't your transition density not depend on the initial time since the SDE's coefficients are not time-dependent?

Comment: I know that the transition density is locally Lipschitz for any fixed initial condition and horizon $T$, i.e., $|f(x,T|x_0,0)-f(y,T|x_0,0)| \leq C_S |x-y|$.
However, it is possible that I can adapt the method used in the paper for computing this constant to show that it is actually Lipschitz in both $x$ and the initial condition.
In this sense, the problem probably becomes much simpler. I will see if this works out.